# How to make spring boot embedded tomcat to accept gzipped request data

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, gzip, http-compression, embedded-tomcat-8

I hava a spring boot API using the embedded tomcat . I want to make the API to accept compressed request body . I could find references on making compressed responses only .
Could anyone please share what needs to be changed to support gzipped request payload ?

Comment: Have you tried to set server.compression.enabled=true

Comment: @SimonMartinelli : that will compress the response only right ?

Comment: I'm not sure. Why don't you try?